# Where Is My Material Textures Influence Panel?

Tags: texturing, materials

thanks for reading.

So I've got a stumper.

I'm working on a character right now and I've begun work on his hair.

I was going through some tutorials to make sure I knew where I was headed with transparent textures in Blender Render. However, when I went looking for the influence panel it was missing! Here's what my selection of panels actually looks like.
[image]

I went looking online for help. Everyone and everything suggests the influence panel should still be present, even the manual. So, I put together [a .blend file](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/influence/material.html) to spread around and ask for help.

Now here's where I really got confused. I opened this .blend on another pc to make sure it was working and that pc's version of Blender DOES have the influence panel, right where it's supposed to be!

Just to be clear, here's the breakdown:

- PC A does not have influence panel
- PC B does have influence panel
- PC A and B are both running Blender 2.77a
- PC A has the 3Dcoat applink, simple3Dcoat applink, and Luxrender addons
- PC A runs Windows 10
- PC B runs Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after I posted this, I narrowed down the answer!

After tracking down the differences between each set up one by one I realized I had forgotten one alteration: PC A's version of Blender had the Luxrender addon. After a very brief search I discovered [this Luxrender bug.](http://www.luxrender.net/mantis/view.php?id=1649)

**Deactivating Luxrender and reopening Blender did the trick.** The influence panel is back!

Thanks to anybody who came by. Maybe this will help someone else.